# Visual Studio Code / Atom Editor - Syntax Highlighting via function/object

Tags: javascript, syntax, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

Is it possible to write a plugin for language syntax support programmatically? I mean to get the content of current open file into my program and give back a tokenized syntax data structure?
Something like:

```
editor.onChange((fileContent) => {
    return tokenizeForVSCode(fileContent);
    // return tokenizeForAtome(fileContent);
});
```

## EDIT:

To improve my question... I want to use a function that receives the content of a file (e.g. currently opened js file) and than return an object that tells vscode/atom how to highlight the the syntax in this file.

I know this is usally made with regular expressions in a .tmLanguage.json file. But I would like to use a propgram that produces a array of tokens or a AST. Something like:

```
[
    { "type": "keyword", "position": 1, "source": "if",...},
    { "type": "operator", "position": 13, "source": "+",...},
]
```

Is this possible in vscode or atom plugins? And if YES: how should the object structure looks like?

Comment: I think that your question is not totally clear. Would be nice if you could explain more what is tokenized syntax

Comment: @SirPeople : I added more information to my question. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to look at creating a custom grammar for Atom: https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/creating-a-grammar/